# Firestore blocking users and their posts

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a social media application which has following collections in it's firestore structure as:

```
UserActivity
   --- Post 1 id
       --- Post 1 data

   --- Post 2 id
       --- Post 2 data

   --- Post n id
       --- Post n data
```

Here "UserActivity" is a collection of posts that contains the documents with id's and the key value pairs inside the document. One of the key is "userRef", that contains the id of the user, whose post it is.

Now I want to block the users and once a user is blocked, his/her post should not be seen. The structure for tracking the blocked user is:

```
Blocked
      --- User id 1
          --- "Blocked user 1 id" : true
          --- "Blocked user 2 id" : true
          --- "Blocked user n id" : true

      --- User id 2
          --- "Blocked user 1 id" : true
          --- "Blocked user 2 id" : true
          --- "Blocked user n id" : true
```

"Blocked" is the name of the collection. And User id's are the documents which has the key pairs inside them stating which user has been blocked by that particular user. Eg: User id 1 has blocked user with another user id 2.

Now I am applying these security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents { 
    match /UserActivity/{activity} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/Blocked/$(request.auth.uid)/$(request.resource.data.userRef)+'/true');
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to read the posts of only users that are not blocked by me. But these rules are not working fine.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Show your Firestore data tree as an image.

Answer (score 1):

This ultimately depends on how you are reading the documents as conditional reads require that the user has access to all documents in the collection to list/get documents from within. See: [Security Rules are not Filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters)

You would have to instead filter the documents on the client, but to truly block users from reading, you will have to maintain an index collection of document ID's for each user with their post IDs and read them with a Collection Group Query to find relevant post IDs for each user and pulling posts manually rather than simply scraping your posts.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query